# HTML EDITOR is not visible when I'm using DevExtreme vue.js

Tags: vue.js, devextreme, html-editor

I'm making a new notice-board for my customer.
CRUD is working very well BUT the problem is...

I'm using DxHtmlEditor(by DevExtreme) to make HTML EDITOR. my code like

```
<DxHtmlEditor
  ref="htmlEditor"
  height="600px"
  :on-value-changed="changeTest"
  :value="formData.content"
  :visible="true"
>
  <DxToolbar :multiline="isMultiline">
    <DxItem name="undo" />
    <DxItem name="redo" />
    <DxItem name="separator" />
    <DxItem
      :accepted-values="sizeValues"
      name="size"
    />
    <DxItem
      :accepted-values="fontValues"
      name="font"
    />
    <DxItem name="separator" />
    <DxItem name="bold" />
    <DxItem name="italic" />
    <DxItem name="strike" />
    <DxItem name="underline" />
    <DxItem name="separator" />
    <DxItem name="alignLeft" />
    <DxItem name="alignCenter" />
    <DxItem name="alignRight" />
    <DxItem name="alignJustify" />
    <DxItem name="separator" />
    <DxItem name="orderedList" />
    <DxItem name="bulletList" />
    <DxItem name="separator" />
    <DxItem
      :accepted-values="headerValues"
      name="header"
    />
    <DxItem name="separator" />
    <DxItem name="color" />
    <DxItem name="background" />
    <DxItem name="separator" />
    <DxItem name="link" />
    <DxItem name="image" />
    <DxItem name="separator" />
    <DxItem name="clear" />
    <DxItem name="codeBlock" />
    <DxItem name="blockquote" />
    <DxItem name="separator" />
    <DxItem name="insertTable" />
    <DxItem name="deleteTable" />
    <DxItem name="insertRowAbove" />
    <DxItem name="insertRowBelow" />
    <DxItem name="deleteRow" />
    <DxItem name="insertColumnLeft" />
    <DxItem name="insertColumnRight" />
    <DxItem name="deleteColumn" />
  </DxToolbar>
  <!-- <div v-html="formData.content" /> -->
</DxHtmlEditor>
```

this.
I expected this code work very smooth, but it wasn't.
one of my colleagues said it must be a version problem. but he and I have no idea which dependency is.

please let me know how can I solve this problem.
I look forward to your reply :)
Thank you and enjoy the weekends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need quill or devextreme-quill in your project (depends on the version of devextreme-vue):

If you are using > v20

> The HtmlEditor uses the DevExtreme Quill library. This library is
> installed automatically when you add DevExtreme to your application.

You can see it in: https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/UI_Components/HtmlEditor/Getting_Started_with_HtmlEditor/#Create_an_HtmlEditor

If you are using devextreme-vue < v19

> HtmlEditor is a WYSIWYG editor that allows you to format textual and
> visual content and to output it in HTML or Markdown. HtmlEditor is
> built on top of and requires Quill.

You can see it in: https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/19_2/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxHtmlEditor/

Another issue you may have is: If you are usign devextreme-vue below version 21. The **name** property of DxItem is **format-name**.

You can see an example in: https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/20_2/ApiReference/UI_Components/dxHtmlEditor/Configuration/toolbar/items/

Comment: Cheers! I solve this problem :) I just updated my DevExtreme version from 20.2.5 to 21.1.5 Thanks a lot anyway!!